# Script for Automator service to remove carriage returns and replace with them comma and space within application

Tags: macos, shell, automator

Using automator I'd like to create a service that allows me to take a list

EX.

```
list item 1
list item 2
list item 3
list item 4
```

and remove the return Carriage returns and replace them with a comma and space `,`

EX.

```
list item 1, list item 2, list item 3, list item 4
```

In my research I have come across various ways to remove a space or carriage return but they all look something like this:

```
sed 's/[:space:]+/,/g' orig.txt > modified.txt
```

It's likely I have missed the function I was looking for.  I'm not a programmer by any means and sometimes the things that are said or described goes over my head.

Creating a text document and then modifying it doesn't work for me.  I need to be able to modify it before the document is created.

Is this possible?

My goal is to get a script that I could input into a Automator service that will allow me to select text in an application, right click, select the pre-made function that allows me to remove the carriage returns and replace them with a comma and a space.

Links to articles are also appreciated if in fact this exact question has been asked before.

Any help is appreciated.

Thanks all!

Floyd

Comment: oh, just realize that automator is a program/tool under Mac os.....  let me know if my answer helps, if not at all, i would remove it..

Comment: Opps, Just replied to your earlier comment.  The command didn't work.

Comment: it's ok, I am gonna remove that answer. I have 0 experience with the fruit system.. :)  btw, I add a `file` at the end the line. awk accepts stdin too. you could e.g. `echo foo|awk ...` but I don't know if it helps in your "automator". good luck..

Answer (score 0):

Choose the service template, check output replaces selected text, and add a run shell script action like this and select pass input as arguments:

```
x=${1%$'\n'}
printf %s "${x//$'\n'/, }"
[[ "$1" != "$x" ]] && printf '\n\n' || exit 0
```

- `${var%pattern}` removes a pattern from the end
- `${var//search/replace}` replaces all occurrences
- `printf %s` is like `echo -n` (it doesn't add an extra newline)
- Automator shows an error dialog if scripts don't exit with 0

Comment: Hi Lauri, I pasted the script and followed the instructions you gave me. However, when I select some text, right click and select the service I saved nothing happens. I made sure to set the service to receive "text" in "any application" and  toggled "output replaces selected text" on and off.  I've seen no results.  What could I be doing wrong?  Keep in mind, I'm not a programmer by any means.  Still learning.  I appreciate your help immensely. Thanks.

Comment: Did you change `Pass input` to `as arguments`?

Comment: Yes.  I passed inputs as arguments. And not to be redundant but I want to be sure, here is the sequence of steps I'm doing when trying to use it: select text in an application, right click, select the pre-made function that allows me to remove the carriage returns and replace them with a comma and a space. When you tested it outside of the program, it worked?

Comment: Does the file actually have CR (old Mac) or CRLF (Windows) line endings? The service is only meant to work with LF line endings. You could also copy text and run this in Terminal: `x=$(pbpaste); echo "${x//$'\n'/, }"`.

Comment: The last command worked!  And I'm assuming right now (still figuring out a way to tell definitively) but I should have LF line endings.  I'm on a newer OSX mac. 10.7.5.